# cmake: compiler flag for all build types

Tags: cmake

is there a way to add a compiler flag independently on what the build type is? Or must I append it to all the CMAKE_C_FLAGS_* variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply set `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` (or `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` for C++). They are applied for all configurations.